# SSH into dual boot computer

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, cygwin

So as is usual I have a dual boot Kubunutu / Windows 7 box (with cygwin), at certain static IP of local 192.168.0.x range, and I want to SSH to it from my other boxes regardless of which system it's running.

The thing is - I configured Kubuntu and Windows 7 parts separately, so they have different ssh host  key (that's inherent in these dual boot setup), but also usernames, and `IdentityFile` (that is pretty awkward, I just didn't think much of it when I choose Windows 7 account name) and ssh goes crazy because every time I boot to a different OS it thinks someone is MITMing since key for same IP changed.

What's the best I can do here? Deleting `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and commenting out different part of `~/.ssh/config` every time I log in sort of works, but I'd rather solve it properly-ish.

Comment: Change the static IP: pick another, close one, have your client ping the first static IP; if it responds ssh into it, if it does not, ping the second IP, and if it responds ssh into it.

Comment: IP is determined by NAT router and it depends on ethernet card's MAC. I could modify MAC in bootup/shutdown scripts, but that sounds like a very wrong thing to do.

Comment: You can easily modify the static IP of your pc in both Windows and Linux, and disable the reserved IP address in the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to self-answer that.

First I renamed my user account in cygwin's `/etc/passwd` without changing Windows account name, and moved `/home/myoldname` to `/home/mynewname`.

Then I copied `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` from Ubuntu to cygwin, so I can use same identity key to access both.

Then I addded following lines in `~/.ssh/config` on machine accessing them:

```
Host 192.168.*.*
  User mynewname
  IdentityFile /path/to/identity.key
  UserKnownHostsile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This prevents saving key file, leaving me with just mildly annoying message every time I login:

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.x.x.' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

Just if anyone is wondering, you can have two entries with the same ip address in .ssh/known_hosts. SSH will accept the host if one of the entry is valid.

You just have to manually edit .ssh/known_hosts or you can comment one out, ssh with the other and then uncomment.

Example:

1. You ssh into Kubuntu
2. You add a dash in the entry corresponding to your ip address
3. You ssh into Windows
4. You uncomment the entry for kubuntu in .ssh/known_hosts
5. You can ssh into both systems without any warning or anything

Comment: This is the best answer !!!